# In c# webforms, Get current path with port dosen't return the port

Tags: c#, path, webforms

I work in `localhost:5164` and I use this function to get current path,

```cs
    Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString()
```

and the result is correct, absolute path width port. For example:

```
http://localhost:5164/path/page1.aspx
```

But in a domain this function don't return path with port, (444 is the use from client browser)

```
http://sub.domain.com:444/path/page1.aspx
```

and the result is:

```
http://sub.domain.com/path/page1.aspx
```

I use other functions, but always the result isn't correct:

```
Request.Url.ToString()
Request.Url.OriginalString.ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could build the URL from its parts:

```
var url = Request.Url.Scheme +         // http(s) 
            Uri.SchemeDelimiter +      // //:
            Request.Url.Host +         // sub.domain.com  
            ":" + Request.Url.Port +   // :444
            Request.Url.PathAndQuery;  // path/page1
```

`AbsoluteUri` will not return the port if its the default (80).

Comment: Whatever function of Request I use from the result is without port, but your code Is good to construct a Url

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution to return the URL with the port, on this particular server

```
    Page.ResolveClientUrl("~" + Request.Url.PathAndQuery.ToString())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the port number you can use:

```
Request.Url.Port.ToString();
```

This should return the actual port number and you can verify if it is 444. If you use a default port number for a protocol, like 80 for http, it might not show up when you check the AbsoluteUri value.